# Can we convert array of map to array of model entity class [POJO] without looping?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I need to convert array of Map to a model class which contains memeber variable as array of POJO without looping through variables. For eg as follows:

```
Map<String,String>[] StudentArray= new HashMap[2];

Map<String,String> map1= new HashMap<String,String>();
map1.put("id","1");
map1.put("name","ABC");

Map<String,String> map2= new HashMap<String,String>();
map1.put("id","1");
map1.put("name","DEF");

StudentArray[0]=map1;
StudentArray[1]=map2;
```

Model class is:

```
class Student{

   private String id;
   private String name;
}

class StudentArray{

   Student[] student;
}
```

I need to convert array of map to StudentArray model POJO.

Comment: Why you don't need looping?

Comment: Sure. You can copy and paste the same code as many times as there are elements in the  array. But why would you do that instead of using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams in Java 8 helps in implementing internal iteration.
Below piece of code will work.

```
List<Student> studentList = Arrays.stream(StudentArray).map(studentMap-> 
getStudentObject(studentMap)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here studentMap will iterate as an instance from StudentArray[] and below method will convert each of these instance to Student POJO class, which is collected in List studentList.

Use com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3 jar to use ObjectMapper's convertValue method:

```
private Student getStudentObject(Map studentMap){
    ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper(); // // jackson's objectmapper
    return m.convertValue(studentMap, Student.class);
    }
```